# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, routes

I have a rails app where I can create and edit records.  I've created a form to enter data which works fine when I use the new/create actions.  It will create a record no problem.  But when I hit the edit action it gives me an undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class.

I'm not sure what this means.  Can someone give me a hand?

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@patient) do |f| %>

<%= f.label :Patient_Last_Name %>
<%= f.text_field :patient_last %>
<%= f.label :Patient_First_Name %>
<%= f.text_field :patient_first %>
<%= f.label :Patient_DOB %>
<%= f.date_select :patient_dob %>

<%= f.label :Primary_Diagnosis %>
<%= f.collection_select(:diagnosis_id, Diagnosis.all, :id, :diagnosis_name)%></br>
<%= f.label :Primary_Physician %>
<%= f.collection_select(:physician_id, Physician.all, :id, :physician_name)%></br>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

View Code:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_patient_path(patient), :class => 'btn btn-close btn-mini'%></td>
```

Controller Code:

```
  def edit
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Edit view:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

When I remove the partial render from the form, the URL will go to the correct route/url.  But I keep getting that error when the form partial is rendered.

Comment: So I printed out the variable in the view with @patient.inspect and it gave me nil.  My browser points to the right url/record.  The records all have data in them.  It's like the controller is not assigning the variable properly but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra end statement in my controller which was cutting off half of the class which included the edit action.  This was not allowing me to use the edit action.  Once this typo was fixed things started working normally.

Sorry for the confusion.